# How do you emit a hit.item with node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am detecting a hit.item in my script and using it to fill squares of a grid.

The draw part of my script is working but when I emit the item, it doesn't work.

I guess that hit.item is a structure and I need to break it down before sending?

That is a guess though - this is my first node.js script!

Can anyone shine a light?

```
io.on('drawFill', function( data ) {
console.log('drawFill received:' , data.target);
drawFill(data.target);

function onMouseMove(event){
var hit = project.hitTest(event.point);
if (hit){

    drawFill(hit.item);
    emitFill(hit.item);
    console.log('drawto',hit.item);
} else {
    console.log("no hit");
}
}

function drawFill(item){
item.fillColor = "#00F8FF";
 //console.log(item);
}
function emitFill (target) {

 // Each Socket.IO connection has a unique session id
var sessionId = io.socket.sessionid;

// An object to describe the circle's draw data
var data = {

target : target
};
// send a 'drawCircle' event with data and sessionId to the server
io.emit( 'drawFill', data, sessionId );
}
```

Comment: can you state how have you defined 'io'?

Comment: Err.. like this: io = io.connect('/');

Comment: Pretty sure that bit works as I am getting messages written to console in my io.on function. Its just that the data I'm receiving - data.target - does not work when sent to my draw function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but are you emitting event `drawFill` from client and also receiving on client side? Also, socket.io emits data in the form of text or JSON i.e, in property:value form. So if your item has multiple properties then you really need to break it down.
Suppose your item has two properties e.g color, name etc  and you want to send to server, then you should better do it as:

```
var data = {color: target.color,
            name: target.name,
            sesId: sessionid}
```

and emit as

```
io.emit( 'drawFill', data);
}
```

This will go to socket.io server.

Comment: Thanks but for some reason this is giving me : Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON . Can't work out why. Not sure if this was the problem all along. Going round in circles myself!

Comment: Thanks - yesterday I stumbled upon the realisation that I needed to send individual properties. I think I have it almost working now, just having a lot of syntax headaches and finding debugging difficult even with my simple script. What does "Converting circular structure to JSON" actually mean? ie what is a circular structure - an item which references itself?

Comment: Yeah something like that but I don't know much about that, I don't know where it is happening in your code but it's a headache when using socket.io. It also happens when you have an HTML element to send. Probably hit.item has HTML elements